# AngularJS unusually slow in IE8

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, optimization, internet-explorer-8

I am currently making an angular app for IE8 in conjunction with a version for more modern browsers. I have begun running into some speed problems however. In Firefox/Chrome the initial page loads in roughly a second but in IE8 it can take up to ten or fifteen seconds. I expected IE8 to be slower than modern browsers, but not by this much. I have installed dynatrace to try isolate the problem and as far as I can tell it seems to be the AJAX that is slowing down the site. I am using websockets for the modern browser so it is falling back to long polling, I believe, for IE8. If anybody has had similar experience with this or could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated. Also any general tips on angular optimisation would also be greatly appreciated. If more information is needed just ask and I will share it.

Comment: I am one of the engineers on dynatrace. If you want feel free to export the data and send it to me and I take a closer look at this. I am doing a lot of performance analysis sessions - happy to provide an additonal point of view on this. Here is how you can get in touch with me: http://bit.ly/sharepurepath Andi

Comment: In my case, I wrap all the ajax requests to a jsonp request, and included it in page load.